# Magento 2 Editing phtml files in Production Mode

Tags: magento2, phtml, developer-mode, production-mode

I have a Magento 2 store in **"production mode"**

> My question is, If I want to change a **phtml file**, do I need to change to **developer mode** or is it enough to execute **`setup:static-content:deploy -f?`**

Comment: Enable developer mode only when you want to see error on the screen.

Comment: and after changing in phtml file you dont need to run deploy command. Just clean the cache and thats it.

Comment: So when I change a phtml file I just need to execute setup:static-content:deploy -f to get results?

Comment: I did but the changes does not appear ? I use a custom theme

Comment: no, when you make some change in phtml just flush the cache and see your changes on the browser.

Comment: which file you are trying to chnage?

Comment: So I went to app> design >Frontend template_name> template_name2>template>Magento_Customer> templates>form>forgot password.phtml

Comment: I flushed cache but nothing happens

Comment: your directory looks wrong it should be like 
app/design/frontend/Theme vendor Name/theme name/Magento_Customer/templates>form>forgot password.phtml

Comment: can you check if a file exists in var/view_preprocessed? if yes, then your file rendering from there

Comment: This is correct so do I need to execute setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Shailesh you are correct I have content in view_preprocessed. So do I need to change those files ?

Comment: Hello @MakeUp You should use the Developer mode while you are developing. In Developer mode, static view files are generated every time they are requested.

Comment: And I have explained the reason for that, why you should use Developer mode while you are developing.

Comment: Aaditya thank you very much for your help. So I should always change to developer mode change the phtml file and then change back to production mode ? This is really annoying.

Comment: you can remove view_preprocessed from your project folder and try once.

Comment: No, you don't need to change the mode you can  setup:static-content:deploy in product mode also, but it shouldn't  a methodology to follow. Production mode is like when you project is live and there will be rare cases where any file will be changed.

Comment: Where developer mode is only for development purpose... But why do you need to change the files frequently  in production mode ?

Comment: In admin there is setting: stores -> configuration -> advanced -> developer -> Template Settings -> Minify HTML -> set it no -> so file will render directly from your custom theme folder not from var/view_preprocessed

Comment: @MakeUp Just tell me one thing, Is your project is live or still in local system ?

Comment: My project is live but I have one in localhost too. So to summarize: When I change anything on phtml files I need to execute the deploy command or I can switch to developer mode and change it their and switch back to production mode correct ?

Comment: Yes you can do both, But preferable is deploy command in production mode.

Comment: For more understanding :) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Comment: Yes and for time saving purpose you can use language wise deployment.

Comment: you can deployment theme wise, language wise..

Comment: But why on localhost it changes directly ? So I did not execute deploy ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92734/discussion-between-aaditya-and-make-up).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92751/discussion-on-question-by-make-up-magento-2-editing-phtml-files-in-production-mo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In production mode you can directly run static deploy command so you don't need to add -f in your command.

There is no need to change developer mode on production environment every time you change in phtml. Just run static deploy command and it will work fine.

For production:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

For development:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: In Developer mode -f is used it means forceful deployment. no need to add -f in production mode

Answer (score 8):

**Production mode** :

- If you are in **Production mode** and you made any change in `PHTML` file or any view files then it
  requires running the **deploy tool** again.
- In this mode, static view files **are not created on the fly** when they
  are requested; instead, they have to be deployed to the pub/static
  directory using the command-line tool.

**Developer mode** :

- If you make any change in `PHTML` file or any view files are
  immediately visible.
- Uncaught exceptions and errors displayed in the web browser.
- Automatic code compilation.

Deploy static view files

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

But to  deploy static view files for the **en_US** language, command must be like this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

**Command options:**

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [<languages>] [-t|--theme[="<theme>"]] [--exclude-theme[="<theme>"]] [-l|--language[="<language>"]] [--exclude-language[="<language>"]] [-a|--area[="<area>"]] [--exclude-area[="<area>"]] [-j|--jobs[="<number>"]]  [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [-f|--force]
```

> My question is, If I want to change a **phtml file**, do I need to change to **developer mode** or is it enough to execute **`setup:static-content:deploy -f?`**

---

> You should use the **Developer mode** while you are developing.   In Developer mode, static view
>    files are generated every time they are requested.

Comment: Good explanation. +1

Comment: Am I crazy or this wasn't needed at some point before? I swear I remember doing some hotfixes and it worked just by cleaning the `block_html` and `full_page` caches, but this isn't working anymore 